# Confusion about using shell pipes from vim command mode

Tags: shell, vim, pdflatex

I have a function (written below; source: [TeX SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459470/135122)) that uses pipes in the shell which I'd like to use in vim command mode. It works as intended from the shell but returns an **E34: No previous command** error if entered in vim command mode. Full credit goes to [jirislav](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134632/jirislav) in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459470/135122) on TeX SX.

> : | pdflatex -halt-on-error src.tex | grep '^!.*' -A200 --color=always

I'd very much like to have this shell functionality from the vim command line if anyone can help with that.

I tried the following from within vim command mode:

> :! : | pdflatex -halt-on-error src.tex | grep '^!.*' -A200 --color=always

returns the E34 error. No pipes hides all compilation; however, it also doesn't output errors. Deleting 1 of 2 of the pipes also returns E34 errors for me.

I tried further troubleshooting to no success and here are some results of that. The help for :! says

> a pipe '|' in {cmd} is passed to the shell, you cannot use it to append a vim command. See :bar

and :bar says (something that's referred to as escaping it out I think)

> '|' can be used to separate commands, so you can give multiple commands in one line. If you want to use '|' in an argument, precede it with '\'.

I tried doing what :bar suggests, i.e.

> :! : \| pdflatex -halt-on-error src.tex \| grep '^!.*' -A200 --color=always

The result is it hides everything, including compilation errors that I want to see. So I've come to the conclusion that I have no clue how to properly use shell pipes in vim command mode.

If you aren't a LaTeX user, all that the function is meant to do is the following. *pdflatex* compiles what's going on in vim into a pdf file. Enacting :! pdflatex % from vim's command mode outputs a whole slew of processing text and interrupts workflow; the grep in the function yanks out compilation errors, if they exist. The function, then, is meant to hide all output from *pdflatex* unless a compilation error occurs, in which case it outputs only the error and outputs it in red.

If anyone cared to explain the E34 error and why it doesn't work that would be appreciated, also.

Edit 1: This is now **solved** thanks to filbranden. Below there are a couple pictures attached of a minimal example should anyone come across this later.

[vim file before input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7zcY.png), [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS9Qe.png)

Edit 2: Should you want to stick this in your .vimrc file, you'll need to escape out the pipe before grep, else the *vimrc file* defaults to thinking that pipe is a separator.

Comment: I read your post a few times and I still can't understand what you're trying to achieve... Can you please update your post and state very explicitly **what you're trying to do**? For example: "run pdflatex on the current document and filter error messages and display those etc." Without understanding what you're trying to do, it's hard to help...

Comment: The problem with `: | pdflatex ...` is that `|` is **not** a pipe in Vim command-line, it's actually a command separator (similar to what `;` does in the shell...) `|` is only a pipe if you're running a shell command from Vim. So for example `:! pdflatex ... | grep ...` will work as expected, the `|` is a pipe there.

Comment: If you want to just run an external command, without piping something into it (not sending data to its standard input), then `:! ...` will do that. Yes, you can use `%` to pass the current filename in the command-line, so you can save your changes and use the command to compile your source file. If you want to pipe data to your external command, what you probably want is `:w ! ...` which pipes the contents of the current buffer into the standard input of the external command.

Comment: See `:help :!` for the former, `:help :w_c` for the latter.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input @filbranden ! I edited it and I hope it's clearer now. I'd like to have the functionality of the shell function from within vim's command mode. I have been using :! followed by the function in vim command mode and it doesn't work. I never even heard of :w !. I'll go investigate. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: is this what you're looking for? `:! pdflatex -halt-on-error src.tex | grep '^!.*' -A200 --color=always` This will run pdflatex and pipe it to grep to show the lines starting wit a `!`...

Comment: That gives an *E34: No previous command* error. I have no idea why.

Comment: @filbranden i believe the original shell command used a redundant pipeline `: | ...`, where `:` is basically shell’s no-op

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yeah true that `:` kinda works... But it's probably unnecessary. I don't reproduce the `E34` error reported by the OP...

Comment: I just read `:help E34` and I think I know what the problem is... When running a command in the shell with `:!` then any other `!`s in that line will be replaced with the last command that you ran on a shell. If you haven't, you get that error. So you need `\!` on your grep: `:! pdflatex -halt-on-error src.tex | grep '^\!.*' -A200 --color=always`. Does that fix it for you?

Comment: Woohoo!! That worked great! Thanks so much, @filbranden!! Attaching pictures of a minimal input/output example in the question for anyone who may come across this. Please feel free to make that an answer if you want; nailed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### E34: No previous command

So the answer to your question was hiding in plain sight under [`:help E34`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#E34), which redirects to the `:!` command.

(Vim pro-tip: whenever you get an error from Vim, ask for `:help` on the error code to get more context about it.)

The section on `:!` includes this passage:

> Any `!` in `{cmd}` is replaced with the **previous external command**. But not when there is a backslash before the '!', then that backslash is removed.

You *did* have a `!` in your command, as part of the `grep` regular expression, `^!.*`, so that was triggering the "history" behavior, trying to replace with the previously executed command. But since no command had executed at that point, the command failed with an error.

You can solve it by escaping the `!` with a backslash, which Vim will remove before passing the command to the shell:

```
:! pdflatex -halt-on-error src.tex | grep '^\!.*' -A200 --color=always
```

But note that there are better ways to approach this problem! Let me cover some of them.

### Using systemlist()

One great way to run external commands in Vim is to use the [`systemlist()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#systemlist%28%29) function, which runs the command on a shell, captures its output, splits it into lines and returns a List with the resulting output lines.

So you could start with:

```
let latex_output = systemlist('pdflatex -halt-on-error src.tex')
```

And then use Vimscript commands to check for lines starting with `!` to report to the user.

Note that, unlike with `:!`, the output of `systemlist()` is never displayed to the user (which means you don't switch back to seeing a terminal, possibly a blank one, and after the execution you don't have a "Hit enter prompt.) Which is great!

But that means you need to present that information to the user, when there are errors. A great way to do that is to use the [quickfix window](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html)!

You can use the [`setqflist()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#setqflist%28%29) function to set the contents of the quickfix window.

(For best results, you should set `'errorformat'` appropriately, more on that later.)

### Using vim-dispatch

If you don't like the part of running an external command (either through `:!` or `systemlist()`) that has it *block* Vim until the command execution is completed, then consider installing the [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) plug-in.

It can execute a command for you in background or in a separate terminal, so you're not blocked from editing. It also integrates with the `:make` command and the quickfix window.

### Compiler configuration in vim-latex

Finally, the [vim-latex](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex) plug-in (also known as latex-suite) has configurations to help you run `pdflatex` and report errors.

It includes a Vim [`:compiler`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acompiler) configuration that will [run pdflatex for you](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/master/compiler/tex.vim#L131) as a `:make` program. It also will [set `'errorformat'`](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/master/compiler/tex.vim#L222) to recognize the `! LaTeX Error` string and recognize the line number of the errors, so you can jump to them directly from the quickfix list.

Note that vim-latex also has many other features to help you write LaTeX documents in Vim (besides managing the output generation through the compiler support.) You might want to check these other features as well.

(Since the plug-in has quite many features, I recommend reading the whole documentation to get you started on it.)

Also note that this plug-in is compatible with vim-dispatch (since vim-latex provides a compiler interface and vim-dispatch consumes it), so you can use both together if you like them both!